# import error of ArcFace using python in jupyternotebbok

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, importerror, arcface

When I am importing the package ArcFace.

```
from arcface.metrics import ArcFace
```

It is showning the import error. Like this,

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fe2759a1802e> in <module>
     15 from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
     16 from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
---> 17 from arcface.metrics import ArcFace
     18 from keras.layers import Input
     19 from keras import backend as K

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcface'
```

I have searched for importing it for Anaconda and pip too. I have not found any results. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: module may have different name and you should check it with Google

Comment: Its actually apart of facelib. But this code I got it from GitHub. I have installed that facelib library. But still the same result.

Comment: is this your code or code in some module or code from some tutorial? I don't see `arcface` in `facelib` repo. It mentions [insightface](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface) and I found [insightface/recognition/ArcFace](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/tree/master/recognition) but still it is not `arcface.metrics.ArcFace`. I tried to search `arcface.metrics` with Google and I found only [keras-arcface.metrics.ArcFace](https://github.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface/blob/master/metrics.py)

Comment: You can check in the link here. [link](https://github.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface/issues/2). In this you can get some clarity. But I have tried the code but not working.

Comment: `keras-arcface` is not part of `keras` and you have to install it separatelly. If you put it in your project in folder `arcface` then you can import it as `from arcface.metrics import ArcFace`

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you so much for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of project [keras-arcface](https://github.com/4uiiurz1/keras-arcface) but it is not part of `keras` so you have to install/copy it separatelly.

If you put it in your project in subfolder `arcface` then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can run ArcFace within deepface. The framework is mainly based on keras and tensorflow. It handles model building and downloading pre-trained weights in the background. Besides, it covers face recognition pipeline stages includign detect, align.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
resp = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = 'ArcFace')
```